# Lookup if a value is in a range (the range being in 2 separate columns)

Tags: excel, range, vlookup

Apologies if this is already posted somewhere, I've been searching and still having issues.

In one Excel sheet I have a list of numbers in column A, call it "Sheet1".  In another sheet (call it "Sheet2") I have 3 columns, which is essentially a list of number ranges.  Column A is a beginning range, Column B is an ending range, and Column C is some non-numerical categorization and is the value I want to bring back.  I would also like the range to be inclusive.

Example:

Sheet 1 cell A1 = 78335; Sheet 1 cell A2 = 80000; Sheet 1 cell A3 = 90000

(a) Sheet 2 cell A1 = 78334, Sheet 2 cell B1 = 78335; Sheet 2 cell C1 = "Design"

(b) Sheet 2 cell A2 = 79999, Sheet 2 cell B2 = 80001; Sheet 2 cell C2 = "Art"

(c) Sheet 2 cell A3 = 90001, sheet 2 cell B3 = 99999; Sheet 2 cell C3 = Excel N/A error

The intended return value in this case for (a) would be "Design" since the number is within the inclusive range on sheet 2, the intended value for return value for case (b) would be "Art", and the intended return value for case (c) would be an error because this doesn't fall into any of the ranges provided.

I tried Vlookups, lookups, and index match to no avail.  The Lookup function somewhat worked, but didn't have an upper bound so if there was any errors it would just return the last item on the list (ie. sheet 2 column C).

Help is greatly appreciate!

Regards,

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can mark it "up". Ty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch a vid or two..

- [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vomClevScJQ)
- [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpDG96tOqf4)
- [Video 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeICJoftByo)

Comment: Thanks for the help Dani... very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

You can search using Vlookup, setting the rangelookup to false so that you get the closest match on the lower range column.  Tell the lookup to return the upper range column, and if it is more than the value you are looking for, then you got what you needed, otherwise give a null.  So in sheet 1, cell a2, you'd have something like:

```
=if(vlookup(a1,Sheet2!a1..c3,2,false) >= a1, vlookup(a1,Sheet2!a1..c3,3,false), "")
```

This means you are looking up in the column a of Sheet 2, for the closest number that is lower than the contents of a1 in Sheet 1.  Once found, the value in column b is returned and you then compare it to a1 again, to make sure that a1 is in the range (the value in sheet 2, column b is greater than or equal to it).  If it is, you do the lookup again, but this time return the column c from sheet 2, which is your return value.   If the first lookup did not find something that was in the range, then this returns a blank string.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.I made one tweak though - instead of the FALSE range lookup function, I used TRUE (this gives the approximate).

Comment: Then how about accepting the answer and upvoting it?